# Joomla account creation fields not appearing on profile forms

Tags: profile, joomla

I have exactly the problem listed in this forum post:

https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=11260.0

I'm not able to create any Joomla user via a CiviCRM profile form, because the Joomla user registration fields do not appear on the profile.

- the "Allow User Registration" option in User Manager is set to "yes"
- I've tried setting profiles to both "Give option" and "Require" Joomla account creation
- I've tried custom and simple out-of-the-box profiles
- Permissions all seem to be correct (anonymous users are allowed to create profiles, see all custom data fields, etc.)

I do also have Community Builder installed, but as far as I could discover that shouldn't cause any problems with the fields appearing.

Any ideas what else to check, or how to troubleshoot this further?

Comment: Do your CiviCRM Profile have a email field? Joomla! user registration only appear if you have one email field in the form.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this? Currently experiencing a similar issue.

Comment: I'm seeing this issue suddenly on site where it has been working for a couple years.  Using Civi 5.6.0 and Joomla 3.8.13. Community Builder is not installed. Does anyone have new info on this?

Answer (score 0):

Community builder has a plugin called Community Builder System plugin that can be set to redirect or rewrite Joomla user component URLs. Perhaps this interferes and as a result keeps the field set of user registration URLs inaccessible and so out of view in the profile form.

I thank you for your check-list of steps to get the account creation fields to show themselves. It rescued me when I did not know how and why they kept not appearing in a new profile I was trying to get working.
So: well formulated question that answered me in my quest.